# Advanced Installer: How to pass arguments to executable?

Tags: advanced-installer

I'm using Advanced Installer to wrap up my executable into a  nice friendly package. I would normally launch the executable from the command line via something like this:

```
> myExecutable.exe firstArg secondArg
```

Now I'm trying to add these arguments into the Advanced Installer package somehow but it is unclear how to do this. Some posts have suggested I need to add a private or public property, but they don't explain how to do this well. I feel like there should be some straightforward way how to do this within the AI GUI. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Finish Actions` panel of the `ExitDialog` is a `Launch Application` section.  It allows you to specify your application path and arguments.

As for using a property, use the `Install Parameters` screen to add your public (all caps) or private property and simply reference it as `[MY_PUBLIC_PROPERTY]` in the `Arguments:` text box.

[image: Finish Actions panel]

Comment: @Stefan Don't forget to mark Adam's answer as correct if it helped you, so others can find it easily too. Thanks.